# Large Query with multiple joins throws Stackoverflow exception

Tags: hive, hiveql, hortonworks-data-platform

I need to query the results of a large number of joins. Currently the number of columns should result in about 339 columns and half a billion rows from about 30 joins. This query however throws my a Stackoverflow exception in Beeline CLI. I currently have 10G set for Hive Heap Size.

```
    Error: Error running query: java.lang.StackOverflowError 
    (state=,code=0)
```

So far I've changed

```
    hive.fetch.task.conversion = none
```

and

```
    hive.auto.convert.join = false
```

based, on suggestions I found online but no joy.

Whenever I reduce the number of rows or the number of joins I dont get this error. But even as few as 10.000 rows throws me the error again.

My query look similar to this

```
    select * from schema1.view_1
    JOIN `schema1`.`table1` ON (`view1`.`column1` = `table1`.`column1`)
    JOIN `schema1`.`table2` ON (`view1`.`column2` = `table2`.`column2`)
    JOIN `schema1`.`table3` ON (`view1`.`column3` = `table3`.`column3`)
    ...
    JOIN `schema2`.`table4` ON (`view1`.`column1` = `table4`.`column1`)
    JOIN `schema2`.`table5` ON (`view1`.`column2` = `table5`.`column2`)
    JOIN `schema2`.`table6` ON (`view1`.`column3` = `table6`.`column3`)
```

I expected this query to be used by Tableau to create an extraction and publish it. I know Tableau can handle the volume of data as I've done this before. Right know if I can run this query on Beeline I'm happy. Any suggestions?

Comment: Tip: learn about the difference between "stack" and "heap". Could be useful if you expect to develop computer programs. Then google about which Java system properties control the **stack** size. Then contact your SysAdmin to beg for a change in HiveServer2 start-up configuration.

Comment: For a more global perspective: reporting tools such as Tableau, Business Objects etc. always generate this kind of incredibly complex queries (and I've seen much worse). It cost Oracle and Microsoft an enormous effort so that their query optimisers could sort out that SQL vomit and produce an efficient execution plan; and even with an optimal plan, it is often impractical - that's why there are **Data Marts** to pre-compute part of the query.

Comment: So, you cannot expect Open Source products to give you a good SQL query optimizer for free, so you should do like anyone else running a Data Warehouse since 1994: build Data Marts and use Tableau on top of these. Because "brute force" is not always a solution.

Comment: Hey man thanks for the Tips. You are correct, this is mostly a modeling problem on my part. It would take some work on my part but I do believe its the only way foward. Thanks again.